# Preview mode in Experience Editor is broken

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

Whenever I change to Preview mode in experience editor, some SXA components are throwing exceptions:

> Error Rendering Controller: Sitecore.XA.Feature.Navigation.Controllers.LinkController,Sitecore.XA.Feature.Navigation. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Error Rendering Controller: Sitecore.XA.Feature.GenericMetaRendering.Controllers.HtmlSnippetController,Sitecore.XA.Feature.GenericMetaRendering. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have made your SXA Tenant unpublishable. There seems to be some logic in some components that doesn't resolve the Context (master/web) correctly and needs to have the site published.

Simply make your SXA Tenant publishable (remove publishing restrictions) and publish to resolve this issue.